# MSSQLSRV - filtering out results with duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl

I'm having a frustrating issue with SQL Server.  I need to create a view from a table containing details of files loaded through ETL.  The table contains a file id (unique), filename, serverid (relating to the server it has been loaded onto).

The first 2 letters of the filename is a country code, i.e. US, UK, GB, DE - there are multiple files loaded per country.  I want to get the record with the highest file id for each country.  The below query does this but it returns the highest record PER SERVER, so there may be multiple file ids - i.e. it would return the highest file id for that country on server1 and server2 - I only want the highest record full stop.

I've played with an equivalent query on MySQL and got it working by commenting out the last line (`GROUP BY t.[server_id]`), which seemed to work fine, but of course MSSQLSRV needs all non-aggregates in the `SELECT` to be placed in the `GROUP BY` statement.

So, how can I get the same result in SQL Server - i.e. get one result, with the highest file_id, without getting a duplicate row for a different server_id?

Hope I'm making myself clear.

```sql
SELECT MAX(t.[file_id]) AS FID
    ,LEFT(t.[full_file_name], 2) AS COUNTRYCODE
    ,t.[server_id]
FROM [tracking_files] t
WHERE t.server_id IS NOT NULL
    AND t.[server_id] = (
        SELECT TOP 1 [server_id]
        FROM [tracking_files] md
        WHERE md.[file_id] = t.file_id
        )
GROUP BY LEFT(t.[full_file_name], 2)
    ,t.[server_id]
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the sample data I've been playing with in MySQL, along with the result I got (which is the desired result).

[image: data]
[image: results]

In SQL Server, as I can't comment out that last `GROUP BY` clause, we're seeing e.g. two file_ids for GB (one for server 1 and one for server 2)

Comment: Can you please show sample data and desired results? Word problems are hard, and reverse engineering code that doesn't do what you want is even harder.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sure, editing…

Comment: Try to use window function such as row_number() `row_number() over (partition by LEFT(t.[full_file_name], 2) order by [file_id] desc) seq`
and then select the records with `seq=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT  t.File_ID,
        t.full_file_name,
        t.CountryCode,
        t.Server_ID
FROM    (   SELECT  t.[File_ID],
                    t.full_file_name,
                    CountryCode = LEFT(t.full_file_name, 2),
                    t.Server_ID,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(t.full_file_name, 2) ORDER BY [File_ID] DESC)
            FROM    [tracking_files] t
        ) t
WHERE   t.RowNumber = 1;
```

If you are using a previous version you will need to use a subquery to get the maximum file ID per country code, then join back to your main table:

```
SELECT  t.[File_ID],
        t.full_file_name,
        CountryCode = LEFT(t.full_file_name, 2),
        t.Server_ID
FROM    [tracking_files] t
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MaxFileID = MAX([File_ID])
            FROM    [tracking_files] t
            GROUP BY LEFT(t.full_file_name, 2)
        ) MaxT
            ON MaxT.MaxFileID = t.[File_ID];
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I was messing with partitions but couldn't get it quite right

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive logic inside the 2nd solution. Most people, including me would go with the 1st query because it looks more efficient, but sometimes using 'old school solutions' shows a good understanding.